# Is there a single word for ravens and crows that are speaking?

Tags: single-word-requests

We often hear that the birds are `chirping`.

What is the word for ravens and crows that are speaking?

Comment: by speaking, you mean mimicking sound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although many words can be used to describe the cries of birds, ravens are often described to be "croaking," and crows "cawing." Other words such as "squawking" could work. Just keep in mind that ravens and crows are two species of birds that are depicted as making harsher, grating cries compared to other birds.